# How do you change the collation type for a MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, django, utf-8

I'm having the utf-8 Vs. byte string problems mentioned here: [Django headache with simple non-ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168816/django-headache-with-simple-non-ascii-string)

I don't care about case sensitive matching in the MySQL columns, I just always want UTF-8 strings returned because I find it is impossible to deal with byte strings returned for character columns for non-ascii text.

How do I change my MySQL collation type so that UTF-8 strings are always returned through Django?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html

Comment: I find the case insensitive collations weird; I *expect* my string matches to be case sensitive unless I explicitly ask them not to be... Anyhow, all the UTF8 collations have case sensitive and case insensitive variations, so you can still keep whichever behaviour you prefer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to be aware of the character-set/collation settings at the database/table/column levels. Column-level settings take precedence over the others. Because of this, I'm including commands you can use to perform these changes at each level of the db.

---

Inspect your current configuration (database):

`SHOW CREATE DATABASE db_name;`

Inspect your current configuration (table):

`SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name='tbl_name'`

Inspect your current configuration (columns):

`SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tbl_name;`

---

Change the character-set/collation (database):

`ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Change the character-set/collation (table):

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Change the character-set/collation (columns):

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Comment: Comment @user1450663: As officially stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings), Django doesn't support any way for collation manipulation through ORM.

Comment: What's the difference between table and columns options? Seems both of them changing collation for whole table

Answer (score 5):

In django you must write your own migration:

```
./manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

And fill empty migration with these sql command like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0008_prev_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;'),
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;'),
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;'),
    ]
```

Comment: This was helpful in conjunction with the SQL below in David G's post.

Comment: When you rollback to some migration, it gives `... is not reversible`. How do I use `reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop` with `RunSQL` operation?

Comment: @Hussain you can use `reverse_sql` as second param in `RunSQL`. Elsewere can pass `RunSQL.noop` as `sql` or `reverse_sql` param. [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)

Comment: Yes. That's it I think. But I read here here that I don't need to change the charset at all. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1198655/1637867

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: While useful, this only changes the default for new tables, it doesn't alter the collation for existing ones (which is what the OP needs).

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you really did want to change the collation for just one column (I can't think why you might, but who knows) then this is the syntax to alter a `TEXT` column called `DESCRIPTION` in the `ITEMS` table to UTF-8, binary, non-null:

```
ALTER TABLE ITEMS CHANGE DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;
```

There isn't a case-sensitive UTF-8 collation *per se* but the `utf8_bin` collation works for most cases.