# Force django admin search bar to be case insensitive

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, encoding, character-encoding

My problem is that for one of my models, the search bar from the corresponding admin page is performing a case **sensitive** search when it should be a case **insensitive** search by default.

From what I could find [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/dLy6-FT4Yjs), I feel like this might have something to do with database encoding but from [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/unicode/), it says that Django assumes that everything is UTF-8 encoded and I checked my MySQL table and the fields are encoded in UTF-8.

Could it be due to the presence of Greek characters in one of my field? How can I force a case insensitive search in **at least** the fields that don't contain Greek letters? Currently, the search is case sensitive for all the fields. But it works correctly (case insensitive) for other models.

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200) # Might contain greek letters
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Not sharing the admin class  code as nothing fancy is in here. Just standard combination of `list_display`, `search_fields`, `ordering` and `fieldsets`.

Using Django 1.10

**EDIT**
Here is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_model` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field1` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `field2` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    # Non relevant other fields
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `my_model_field2_63f9df5e_uniq` (`field2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=657 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Now that I see that, it's probably due to `_bin` right? Should I convert to something with `_ci`? What's the way of doing that in Django?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE;` -- need to check collation of the column being searched.

Comment: I edited the question with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE;`.

Comment: Perhaps dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050014/how-do-you-change-the-collation-type-for-a-mysql-column/6052541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8_bin` is case sensitive.  Change to `utf8_unicode_520_ci` (if using MySQL 5.6 or 5.7):

```
ALTER TABLE my_model CONVERT TO COLLATION utf8_unicode_520_ci;
```

Using `LOWER()` may work, but it is slow because it prevents using the index, thereby potentially making queries run a lot slower than they could.

Note:  To allow for Emoji and all of Chinese, `utf8mb4` is needed in place of `utf8`.

Your model specifies 3 unique keys for a single table?  That seems excessive.  Then I am confused by the `CREATE TABLE` -- it shows only 2.  (Note:  `PRIMARY KEY` is `UNIQUE`.)

According to [*Django docs*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings) "In all cases, you set the collation by directly manipulating the database tables; Django doesn’t provide a way to set this on the model definition."  As demonstrated by the OP, using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` via MySQL utilities can tell you what collation is currently being used.

Comment: Thanks I understand now that if I use `utf8_whatever_ci` it will probably solve my issue. I was wondering if there was a Django way of doing that?

Comment: Could you edit your answer to specify that "Django doesn't support any way for collation manipulation through ORM." (that's the other 50% of answer I was looking for) so I can accept your answer? [See this part of the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings). Also the field1 wasn't unique, I edited my question.

Comment: @Cyrlop - Yeah, that doc has a very specific note on collation.  I revamped much of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(field1_lower=Lower('field1')) # annotate each item in the queryset with the code_lower
```

Now search with field1_lower instead of field1. Hope that helps.